# In a Java JTextPane, how do I make the font style not reset to the small unstyled font when the user backspaces back to the edge of the text pane?

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane which I use for html styled editing.  I have one problem which is not exactly critical, but would be nice if I could fix it.  The problem is that when I backspace in the text pane up to the end of the line, the style text I had is reset back to the default font and style for the text pane.
How do I stop this from happening and retain the styling.

I have tried setting the JTextPane with

```
"<html><head></head><body>" +
                "<p style = \"font-size:22; font-family:sans-serif\"></p>" +
                "</body></html>";
```

This works until I save or refresh the html.  Once it is saved or refreshed all the text returns back to the very tiny JTextPane font and all styling is removed.

How do I make it retain the styling when saving, refreshing, or backspacing?

Update: I have tried doing [this](http://www.codeitive.com/0zSqWgVXgP/preserving-formatting-on-empty-html-lines-in-jeditorpane.html), but it only works until I save the text in the text pane and update it.  I tested this in java 1.7 like the link said to do.

Comment: Have you tried using [`setFont(Font)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont(java.awt.Font)) to set the font?

Comment: Yes I have and it has made no change at all.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: My code for why I put the JTextPane is over 2000 lines and it is mixed in so I can't exactly show it.  All I need to know is how to make a normal JTextPane not remove formatting after backspacing up to the edge of a line.